# Making Karma a.k.a Testacular work

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I wanna use Karma (previously known as Testacular) to run some jasmine tests. So I've installed node.js, then I run:

```
npm -g install karma
```

I even installed jasmine

```
npm -g jasmine-node
```

then I used `karma init` it created 'karma.conf.js' where "files" section contains this

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  '*.js',
];
```

and I created a small test file

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  return it("spec with an expectation", function() {
    return expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

now I'm trying to run it `karma start` it throws me an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined`, if I remove the line with `JASMINE`, run again - now it doesn't say anything about jasmine, but throws: `describe is not defined`

So what am I doing wrong?

btw. putting `module('someModule')` in test file doesn't help (`module is not defined` error)

upd: I'm on Windows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in fact I'm pretty sure using global variables (e.g. `JASMINE`) been deprecated in the lastest Karma version - but it's not documented.

It should have been replaced by the `frameworks` options, so you'd only need:

```
frameworks = ["jasmine"];
```

Comment: yup, I got the latest Karma and it worked. Do you mind if I delete the question, seems to be unnecessary to pollute SO with something like that?

Comment: In fact, as this change is undocumented, it seems pretty important to me that there's some trace somewhere.